# Prompt the user if quantity field in a form is less than required

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am currently working on a simple order. The form has fields such as name, phone, address, zip code, product ( a select field) and quantity. What I need is to prompt the user with a message when typing less than 50 in the quantity input field.

Can you please point me in the right direction to achieve this ?

So far the form has been done in HTML.

Comment: [Sure](http://google.com)

Comment: Which language is this C#? VB.net? Please ask a [well formed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with helpful tags and the code snippet you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

For getting a number input in a desired range in HTML, use min, max attributes of input tag(type="number").

```
<input type="number" min="50">
```

This will prompt the user with a message if the user tries to submit the form with a value less than 50.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to detect change in value and validate. This script will execute on `change` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#qty').on('change', function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    checkValue(inputValue);
  });
});

function checkValue(inputValue) {
  if (inputValue < 50) {
    var newInputValue = prompt("Please enter value greater than 50");
    checkValue(newInputValue);
  } else {
    $('#qty').val(inputValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" id="qty" min=50 />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" min="50" name="" id="" required value="">
```

When ever the user submits the form it will prompt if the value entered in the field is less than 50